# Unable to install lxml by pip?Is there anyalternative?

Tags: python, pip, lxml, beautifulsoup

Actually Iam trying to installing lxml because of

> UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

So Iam trying to use lxml.but I could not install due to this error
[image]

I tried to install manually by downloading the latest version also.But couldn't make it.Can any one please help me to sort this out

Answer (score 0):

Probabily you didin't installed the requirements for lxml package. Follow this tutorial: http://lxml.de/installation.html

Pay extra attention to this excert:

> Most MS Windows systems lack the necessarily tools to build software,
>   starting with a C compiler already. Microsoft leaves it to users to
>   install and configure them, which is usually not trivial and means
>   that distributors cannot rely on these dependencies being available on
>   a given system. In a way, you get what you've paid for and make others
>   pay for it.
>
> Due to the additional lack of package management of this platform, it
>   is best to link the library dependencies statically if you decide to
>   build from sources, rather than using a binary installer. For that,
>   lxml can use the binary distribution of libxml2 and libxslt, which it
>   downloads automatically during the static build. It needs both libxml2
>   and libxslt, as well as iconv and zlib, which are available from the
>   same download site. Further build instructions are in the source build
>   documentation.

Comment: thank you!but tried that already.did'nt worked

Comment: Why don't you try urllib? https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Comment: Are you facing this warning when using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: yes iam using **urllib** and **url.request** but for retrieving the specific data it would be complicate using **urllib and regex** so iam using beautifulSoup.Yes Iam facing it when using BeautifulSoup.`soup=BeautifulSoup(readData)
`.regarding the error i mentioned above iam using lxml.Is there any way I could make it without lxml